# Php+Nginx+Varnish on docker-compose, ubuntu18

Tags: nginx, varnish, docker-compose

**!Important. SOLUTION FOUND. Everything below is working fine for me. And this is almost the only case when you may copy solution from the question. For it read "My Configuration" section**

## Main Question

On an attempt to open the homepage (through https 443 or http 80 does not matter) I see 503 Varnish error. It looks like Varnish cannot access Nginx back.

> Varnish Request Log

```
*   << Request  >> 20        
-   Begin          req 19 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1587133057.263443 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1587133057.263443 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       192.168.112.7 46616 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      X-Real-IP: 192.168.112.1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.112.1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   ReqHeader      Host: magento2.docker
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Site: none
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,be;q=0.6
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: mage-banners-cache-storage=%7B%7D; _ga=GA1.2.164324136.1586263205; private_content_version=b9dd22e11f7865017754892a623f70f0; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; mage-messages=; recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.112.1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.112.1, 192.168.112.7
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_return     pass
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       PASS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 21 pass
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1587133057.263600 0.000157 0.000157
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Fri, 17 Apr 2020 14:17:37 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 20
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1587133057.263609 0.000166 0.000009
-   Filters        
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 279
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1587133057.263640 0.000197 0.000031
-   ReqAcct        1164 0 1164 242 279 521
-   End  

*   << BeReq    >> 21        
-   Begin          bereq 20 pass
-   VCL_use        boot
-   Timestamp      Start: 1587133057.263477 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
-   BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: 192.168.112.1
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   BereqHeader    Host: magento2.docker
-   BereqHeader    Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36
-   BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Site: none
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,be;q=0.6
-   BereqHeader    Cookie: mage-banners-cache-storage=%7B%7D; _ga=GA1.2.164324136.1586263205; private_content_version=b9dd22e11f7865017754892a623f70f0; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; mage-messages=; recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.112.1, 192.168.112.7
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 21
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   FetchError     backend default: fail errno 111 (Connection refused)
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1587133057.263561 0.000084 0.000084
-   Timestamp      Error: 1587133057.263564 0.000087 0.000002
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   503
-   BerespReason   Service Unavailable
-   BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
-   BerespHeader   Date: Fri, 17 Apr 2020 14:17:37 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Storage        malloc Transient
-   Length         279
-   BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
-   End
```

## My Configuration

Source code can be found here: 
https://github.com/zhartaunik/magento2-docker

Here are some necessary moments for history:

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  varnish:
    container_name: varnish
    build:
      context: varnish/
    ports:
      - 6081:6081

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: nginx/
    working_dir: /etc/nginx
    ports:
      # {internal_in_docker}:{external_from_browser}
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8001:8001
    volumes:
      - ./magento:/var/www/magento
    env_file:
      - ./.env
...
```

> nginx/etc/vhost.conf

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server magento:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name _;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/magento.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/magento.key;
    keepalive_timeout 300s;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://varnish:6081;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8001;

    server_name localhost;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;
```

**I faced the issue because I didn't use the desired varnish.vcl. If you use this one, everything should work fine for you**

> varnish/etc/varnish.vcl

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 4.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'SSL-OFFLOADED: https'

backend default {
    .host = "nginx";
    .port = "8001";
}
...
```

## How in my understanding it should work

- We open through browser homepage: https://magento2.docker/
- As inside `docker-compose.yml` configured that Nginx is listening to 443 port we go to it's `vhost.conf` section (1st part)
- Because of the row `proxy_pass http://varnish:6081;` we are directing to varnish container through 6081 port.
- `nginx_container> telnet varnish 6081` returns SUCCESS
- According to `docker-compose.yml` varnish configured to listen 6081 (**Is it really required to add this port to yml?**) we walk to `varnish/etc/varnish.vcl` (**Could this file contain only `backend default` section for debug purpose only?**)
- Inside `backend default` we see host=nginx, port=8001. This should direct us to Nginx. `varnish_container> telnet Nginx 8001` returns SUCCESS. ***However looks like directly here WE ARE NOT GOING to Nginx***
- The 2nd part of `vhost.conf` doesn't start to work. If we try to open http://magento2.docker:8001/ Nginx resolves this host and application start working.

## What I'm looking for here

- The solution to a problem
- Two bolded questions above
- Any suggestions how to debug? How to check from varnish container what does respond Nginx?

## Update #1 (Solution was found)

> I've tested your Docker setup and the main thing I notice is that the backend definition of /etc/varnish/default.vcl in your varnish container is the following:
>   backend default {
>       .host = "127.0.0.1";
>       .port = "8080";
>   }

**I found a mistake in DockerFile. I used the default config with wrong host/port settings.** I changed this value and everything started working fine.

Here are the sources (all of them you may find at https://github.com/zhartaunik/magento2-docker):

> varnish/Dockerfile

```
FROM varnish:6.2

COPY etc/varnish.vcl /etc/varnish/
COPY bin/docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh

ENV VARNISH_CONFIG  /etc/varnish/varnish.vcl
ENV VARNISH_STORAGE malloc,2048m
ENV VARNISH_LISTEN  :6081
ENV VARNISH_MANAGEMENT_LISTEN 127.0.0.1:6082
EXPOSE 6081
EXPOSE 6082

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

> varnish/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

exec varnishd \
    -j unix,user=vcache \
    -F \
    -f ${VARNISH_CONFIG} \
    -s ${VARNISH_STORAGE} \
    -a ${VARNISH_LISTEN} \
    -T ${VARNISH_MANAGEMENT_LISTEN} \
    -p feature=+esi_ignore_https \
    ${VARNISH_DAEMON_OPTS}
```

I also removed `depends_on` section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested your Docker setup and the main thing I notice is that the backend definition of `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` in your `varnish` container is the following:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

This of course results in a *Connection refused* error.

When I change it to the following, it does work

```
backend default {
    .host = "nginx";
    .port = "8001";
}
```

Just before sending the 1st request to Varnish, I ran the following command to check which backend will be used:

### Debugging

```
root@a5ddd5873f9a:/etc/varnish# varnishlog -i backendopen
*   << BeReq    >> 17
-   BackendOpen    25 default 172.31.0.9 8001 172.31.0.2 58070

*   << Request  >> 16

*   << Session  >> 15
```

Once the connection is open, the `BackendOpen` tag won't appear in your `varnishlog` output.

In your case `BackendOpen` never appeared in the logs, because you never successfully opened up a backend connection.

An easy way to continuously monitor the health of your backend servers in Varnish, is by associating `probes` as illustrated below:

```
backend default {
    .host = "nginx";
    .port = "8001";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/";
        .timeout = 1s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 5;
        .threshold = 3;
    }
}
```

You can monitor the health by running `varnishlog -g raw` as illustrated below:

```
root@a5ddd5873f9a:/etc/varnish# varnishlog -g raw
  0 Backend_health - default Still sick 4---X-R- 0 3 5 0.001804 0.000000 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

> In this case the backend is `sick` because the `/` URL returns a `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`. If you make sure this is a `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, the health check will pass, and you will not what backend Varnish trying to connect to.

### Potential dependency issues

However, there might also be some `depends_on` issues in your `docker-compose.yml` file:

- Varnish depends on Nginx. If Nginx isn't started on time, Varnish cannot resolve the `nginx` hostname, which it uses as its backend.
- Nginx depends on Varnish. If Varnish isn't started on time, Nginx cannot resolve the `varnish` hostname it needs to proxy its traffic through.

It's a bit of a circular dependency thing. Please check ahead of time, to ensure you're not experiencing these issues.

To make your setup work, I had to make sure Nginx depended on Varnish, otherwise the Nginx container wouldn't start. But I had to remove the Nginx dependency from Varnis, otherwise I was stuck in a circular dependency loop.

### Conclusion

In your `docker-compose` setup, your VCL file doesn't point to the right Nginx backend.

A less likely issue is misconfigured dependencies: if the containers aren't started in the right order, hostnames will be not be accessible at the time the container needs them for proxying reasons. Again: not that likely.

Comment: Looks like everything is working. Thanks for your help. Will update my post soon